# How does monster breeding +'ing work?

Tags: dragon-warrior-monsters

I'm a fan of monster-breeding/raising game Dragon Warrior Monsters (GBC).

When monsters are bred, they get + attributes (sometimes). How exactly does the +'ing work for breeding monsters? I can't quite seem to figure it out.

For example,

- beast + +3 spot slime  = +3 spot slime
- +2 blizzardly + +3 phoenix = +4 rain hawk
- +0 eyeball + +0 devil = +1 one-eyed witch

Comment: +'ing lulzy title :P +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.gamefaqs.com/gbc/197155-dragon-warrior-monsters/faqs/8155

This FAQ should answer all of your questions and more.

Comment: A recap of the relevant points would be great. If that link ever dies, this answer will become useless.